# How to run python flask app and webview simultaneosuly

Tags: python, flask, webview, python-os

I am trying to run flask app and webview simultaneously but it seems that only flask app is running first and blocking the webview to open it.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system('python app.py')
    webview.create_window('Hello world', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    webview.start()
```

Webview command is only initiated once I close the flask server (Ctr+C) but till then webview returns connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your flask app in the background. Here is a sample working example. `os.system('python app.py &')`

main.py

```
import webview
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system('python app.py &')
    webview.create_window('Hello world', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    webview.start()
```

app.py

```
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory 
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application. 
from flask import Flask 

# Flask constructor takes the name of 
# current module (__name__) as argument. 
app = Flask(__name__) 

# The route() function of the Flask class is a decorator, 
# which tells the application which URL should call 
# the associated function. 
@app.route('/') 
# ‘/’ URL is bound with hello_world() function. 
def hello_world(): 
    return 'Hello World'

# main driver function 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # run() method of Flask class runs the application 
    # on the local development server. 
    app.run()
```